# Is it possible to delete an ERC-20 token contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, tokens, erc-20

Is it possible, that someone creates a new token on Ethereum let it be XYZ, an ERC-20 token.
Can he later call a destructor func that will wipe off all funds from all people that are using that system?
Or could he redirect all money to his account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contract supports such functionality then yes he can call its `selfdestruct` function (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#deactivate-and-self-destruct). But this functionality has to be code inside the contract when the contract was deployed - the functionality can't be added afterwards (all contract codes are immutable).

Typically this is not implemented in contracts so typically there's no way to remove contract from the blockchain.